# Will the google crawler miss the footer content if we implement unlimited lazy loading of our Products in our Catalog Page on our Ecommerce Website?

Tags: ecommerce, footer, lazyloading

Our SEO expert has suggested we not do lazy load and do pagination as they said google crawler will not be able to crawl footer content if we implement unlimited lazy loading of our Products in our Catalog Page. Is this true?

Comment: Forget about Google.  You have to remove the footer for users with lazy loading.  There **is no way for users to scroll to a footer** when you have infinite scroll.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how are you going to use Lazy Load. If it is just for images (the URL structure will not change) probably you will not have any problem and Google would be able to index them. [Check John's Mueller discussion](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/968763936249085953) for more information.

If you are going to load new content probably that will be out of Google's sight. Despite that [Google bot can render the site with javascript](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/crawl-javascript-seo/), if the new content is loaded after 5 seconds it will not be indexed.

> The rendered page snapshot is taken at 5 seconds, so content needs to
>   be loaded by that time, or it just won’t be indexed for each web page.

Nevertheless, run a test and use [Fetch as Google for websites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) in order to check how Google will see your site. If Lazy Load content doesn't appear in there, you shouldn't use it.